# Trying to do 2 + 3 in Visual Basic. Getting 23 instead

Tags: vb.net, calculator

I am really new to Visual Basic. So I am trying to make a Windows Form Application in Visual Basic which takes two numbers from two textboxes. While running the app, I attempted to calculate 2 + 3 but get 23 instead. What's wrong?

```
Public Class CalcForm
    Private Sub sumBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles sumBtn.Click
        Dim res As Integer
        res = firNum.Text + secNum.Text
        Convert.ToDecimal(res)
        resultNum.Text = res
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: your adding secnum.text which is string. add: `res = convert.ToInt32(firNum.Text) + convert.ToInt32(secNum.Text)`

Comment: The line `Convert.ToDecimal(res)` in this code does nothing. What were you hoping it would do?

Comment: Thanks so much, let me try it.

Comment: @NiazM.Sameer any news?

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you are adding two strings together:

```
firNum.Text + secNum.Text
```

This will not do an addition.

Use numbers instead:

```
Dim res As Decimal
res = Convert.ToDecimal(firNum.Text) + Convert.ToDecimal(secNum.Text)
resultNum.Text = res
```

I used decimal since you where using it as well before.
For the convert to work you need to **make sure your textbox use only numbers.**

You can use a check for instance: `IsNumeric()`

Comment: Congrats to an even 1000 reputation! - Whoops... I ruined the evenness... ;)

Comment: @VisualVincent Nooooooooooooooooooooooo you **evil** man! hahaha thanks for the uptvote :p

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class CalcForm
    Private Sub sumBtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles sumBtn.Click
        Dim res As Integer
        Dim first, second As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(firNum.Text, first) AndAlso Integer.TryParse(secNum.Text, second) Then
            res = first + second
            resultNum.Text = res.ToString()
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid input")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks but could you kindly tell what line 5 means?

Comment: If the text in each box both successfully convert to an `Integer`, then add them and display the output in `resultNum`, otherwise display a `MessageBox`

Comment: Integer.TryParse attempts to convert the first parameter to Integer. If successful, the result is stored in parameter 2 and the function returns True. Otherwise it will return false

Answer (score 0):

I think it's normal, you need to convert firstNum and secNum to Integer, otherwise you are just concatening two string values :

```
res = firNum.Text + secNum.Text
```

To convert string to integer use `CInt()`.

Then you should be able to do 2+3

Answer (score 0):

"5" is different to 5
You could use a [Func](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) so that even if you have string of a number, it will convert it to an decimal by itself as long as it is an decimal and not a character.

```
 Dim addTogether As Func(Of Decimal, Decimal, Decimal) = Function(num1, num2) num1 + num2
    Try
        Console.WriteLine(addTogether("5", 5)) ''output 10 even with a string as the first character
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
```